# Window Vs document.documentElement best practices

Tags: javascript, scrolltop, onscroll

I have a simple page I want to make the top div to be fixed when I scrolled down and a "To Top" div to go back to the top of the page.  I used document.documentElement.scrollTop to get my current position of scrolling from top and `document.documentElement.onscroll` to call the function.  But when I set the "To Top" div, I had to use `window.scrollTo(0,0)` function to go back to the top of the page because `document.documentElement.scrollTo(0,0)` did not work.  What is the difference between `window` and `document.documentElement`?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>scroll demo</title>
  <style>
  #heading {
    color: white;
    background:steelblue;
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:-20px;
    padding:5px;
  }
  p {
    color: green;
  }
  span {
    color: red;
    display: none;
  }

  #top{
    padding:5px;
    border:dotted 2px steelblue;
    box-shadow: -3px -3px 3px;
    background:steelblue;
    width:75px;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    display:none;
    opacity:0.9;
    border-top-right-radius:100%;
    border-top-left-radius:100%;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="heading"><h1>Try scrolling the iframe.</h1></div>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>

<div onclick="top_function()" id="top">
<h3>To Top</h3>
</div>


<script>
    document.documentElement.onscroll = function(){ //a function is call     when scroll using .onscroll 
var x = document.documentElement.scrollTop;  //x is the current scroll position of document
if(x > 0){  //set greater than zero to avoid the annoytingblinking effect
document.getElementById("heading").style.position="fixed";
document.getElementById("heading").style.top="-20px";
document.getElementById("heading").style.left="10px";
}
else{
document.getElementById("heading").style.position="absolute";
document.getElementById("heading").style.top="-20px";
document.getElementById("heading").style.left="10px";
};

if(x > 100){
document.getElementById("top").style.display="inline-block";

}
else{
document.getElementById("top").style.display="none";
};
}; //ends function onscroll


function top_function(){
window.scrollTo(0,0);
};
```

Comment: "Best practice" questions tend to get closed as opinion based. You should probably leave that part out or define what you need "best" to mean (ex. "Which one is faster?" )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the DOM API is hard. Depending on what you are doing, jQuery has the potential to give you a lot more bang for your development buck in terms of understandability, readability, maintainability, and cross-platform compatibility.

That being said, `document.documentElement` is a reference to the `<HTML/>` node of the document. Unless something really odd is going on (eg `html { overflow: scroll; }`), `scrollTop` for `<HTML/>` should always be `0` just as other nodes that are not scrolled.

Direct page scrolling actually occurs on the `window`. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ewq25bs/) shows how to listen for the scroll offset changes on the window, get the current scroll offset of the window, and scroll the window to a new offset.

For the record, if you want to make a link that scrolls to the top of the page, there is no need for JavaScript at all, just create a link to `#`. As long as you don't intercept the native processing of the link, the defined behavior is to scroll back to the top of the page.

Comment: I have tried :

` window.onscroll = function(){
    var x = window.scrollTop;  
 if(x > 0){
    //function
 }`

Comment: The window is not a DOM node and does not have a `scrollTop` property (`window.hasOwnProperty('scrollTop'); // => false`); however, you can use `window.scrollY` to find the window's scroll offset.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for differentiating between the DOM and BOM.  So I replaced `document.documentElement.onscroll` with `window.onscroll`; AND `document.documentElement.scrollTop` with `window.pageYOffset`  This will accomplish my goal for this project and eliminate confusion.

Answer (score 0):

A **clarifying-property-discrepancy** is `document.documentelement.scrollHeight` and `window.scroll(0,0)`, `window.scrollY`/`window.offsetHeight`/`window.innerHeight` all html must be a *div `C or C++` class something-or-other*, and div-elements only have `offsetTop` and `scrollTop` that you can set, from a child's `offsetTop`, to; only the `document.documentelement` has access to the scrollHeight, which may not even be a direct reference to window, but its container.